# Is it possible to say which pointer was allocated by cudaMalloc and which by malloc?

Tags: c, memory-management, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

For example, I have a float pointer in the host code

```
float *p
```

Is it possible to determine a type(device/host) of memory to which he points?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a [UVA system](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED), the runtime API function [`cudaPointerGetAttributes`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED_1gab5cad40942fd554556035741d3fe5a2) can provide additional information about pointers that are allocated with a runtime API function such as `cudaMalloc` or `cudaHostAlloc`.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861161/cuda-find-out-if-host-buffer-is-pinned-page-locked), we can inferentially determine that the pointer must have been allocated by a non-CUDA function (e.g. `malloc`) if the error return `cudaErrorInvalidValue` is given.